# Playing Audio in Background Thread (when Screen is Off) Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, audio, cordova, cordova-plugins

is there any Cordova/Phonegap media plugin available, which can play the audio in background, when screen is locked, particularly for Android. This feature is there by default for iOS, but this doesn't work for Android. I am looking for Cordova/Phonegap media plugin, which works even the screen is turned off for both Android and iOS. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess things changed because nowadays I can easily have the sound play in background on Android, but on iOS it fades out as soon as I switch app. There are also several background plugin specifically for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but in case anyone needs it.

Phone gap supports audio playing as a built in API. I've had success getting it to work even when the screen is locked. The link to the API page is below:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

Comment: Does the phonegap plugin allow for playback of songs while the app is in the background on iOS and Android? i.e. when the user navigates to another app.

Comment: Looking at the Android Source on GitHub, it looks like yes, but if the screen is turned off then it looks like it will stop playing. I haven't tested it though

Comment: Thanks for replying. What exactly on the source on github makes you think it does? I could not find where they start a "Service".

Comment: Np. Well from what I know (which may be flawed) you only need a service with a wake lock if you want to keep playing audio when the screen is off. If the app is just in the background than the app still has control of the system resource (audio) until it releases or the system forces it when it stops the app. But that may be completely wrong

Comment: Got it. Will test and report back.